# Webservices for Android

Tags: php, android, web-services, rest, soap

I already have built a web application using php and mysql. Now i am trying to build an Android application to support the web-application. So, basically what i want is my android app should access all the data from the server.

The user basically be able to do CRUD with live data stored on the server.  That means i have to expose the data on top of webservices. The data may be array of sales-orders, complete info of an individual saleorder etc. SO can any one suggest me the best way of designing the webservice(rest or soap) and what would be the best way to return the data to be used by android(xml or json or object or array of fully formatted html output).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you see [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Comment: Think you're going to have to build a simple API to expose data within your application. Return the data as JSON and parse it within the andriod app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see Which is the best PHP RESTful API Framework for your project!

[image]

there few frameworks that helps to build REST API's for PHP.

[Epiphany](https://github.com/jmathai/epiphany)

[Fat Free](http://fatfreeframework.com)

[Flight](http://flightphp.com)

[Restler](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler)

[php-rest-service](https://github.com/marcj/php-rest-service)

**[More..](http://davss.com/tech/php-rest-api-frameworks/)**